# Full-screen Canvas is low res

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I've looked at the questions here and followed the answers but my canvas is still low resolution:

**CSS:**

```
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**JS: Initialise Canvas (called once when page load and again on window resize)**

```
function initCanvas() {
    $('#canvas').width($(window).width());
    $('#canvas').height($(window).height());
}
```

**Drawing line with**

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

**Result**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5XrK/)

You can see that the line appears low res. I would like a canvas that is full window but appears sharp.

NB: I use absolute position and z-index -1 for canvas because I would like it to appear behind anything else I later add on the page.

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
</canvas>
```

We can't set the width and height of the canvas element using css, since it won't get rendered properly as document says. You have to set its

or you have to use

```
function initCanvas() {
    $('#canvas').attr("width",$(window).width());
   $('#canvas').attr("height",$(window).height());
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U5XrK/6/)

Comment: beat me to it.  +1 :)

Comment: [punches self in face]

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate width/height values for a canvas:

- the element, sized via the element's `style` property or css.  These dimensions are used for rendering the element within the document.
- the canvas area, sized with the `width` and `height` properties of the element.  These dimensions are used for drawing on the canvas via its context.

You are successfully resizing the element with jQuery's `width()` and `height()` methods, which are shorthand for changing `element.style.width` and `element.style.height`.

All you are missing is setting the canvas's area, which is a property of the canvas element.  You can do this with jQuery's `prop()` method:

```
$('#canvas').prop({
    width: x,
    height: y
});
```

Or, if you want to do it all at once:

```
var dimensions = {
    width: x,
    height: y
};

$('#canvas').css(dimensions).prop(dimensions);
```

And lastly, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5XrK/10/)

Answer (score 2):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/U5XrK/3/

***Q:*** I would like a canvas that is full window but appears sharp.

***A:*** Set the width and height of the canvas to be the same as the window's in canvas' initiation time:

---

**Code:**

```
// Draw on canvas
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = $(window).width();   // Add this to your code
c.height = $(window).height(); // Add this to your code
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

---

**Explanation:** The original rendered size of the canvas is not affected when you resize the produced image using CSS, so basically you are trying to scale up a smaller image which results in lower quality. If your canvas has the intended size when getting created you won't have this scaling issue.

Answer (score 1):

> [Canvas consists of a drawable region defined in HTML code with
>   **height and width attributes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element).

When you give a value to its CSS width/height - it is similar to doing the same thing to an IMG element - you are scaling it, rather than setting its actual dimensions.

So you should be setting the canvas' HTML attributes for the actual dimensions, instead of its CSS.

Answer (score 0):

U should use the mothod under:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
c.width = 500;
c.height = 500;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: You're setting the width/height to 500px? That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: U can just change it to c.width = window.innerWidth;c.height = window.innerHeight;